# Cannot find reverse lookup of User model

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django 2.0 and I have created a custom user model, if it helps.

I want to be able to retrieve the set of role instances for a given user account. A user account can be included as an Owner or an Employee for a given Company instance. However, when I am trying to do user.employee_set (or user.owner_set), then I get no results.

User Class

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,unique=True,null=False,blank=False)

    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
```

Employee Class

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user','company'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='employee_accounts')
    company = models.ForeignKey(to='Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Owner Class

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user','company'),)

    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='owner_accounts')
    company = models.ForeignKey(to='Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I lookup either user.owner_accounts or user.employee_accounts, then I get an empty set of results. I have checked that the user account does in-fact have an employee record, and an owner record, that each reference it. If I do Employee.objects.get(user=user) or Owner.objects.get(user=user) then it will succeed and retrieve the appropriate user wrapper object. Am I misunderstanding something about how ForeignKey works? I thought this setup would allow me to do a reverse lookup, unless I messed-up something in the model definitions.

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User' did you defined ?

Comment: @HemanthSP, I have set AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User' because I have an "accounts" app that defines a custom user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check like this this should work

```
u1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)
u1.employee_accounts.all()
```

Comment: There was a bit of confusion with looking at the details of the request variable. I did not realize that the RelatedManager in the request object simply contained a QuerySet (and thus would not have resolved it until called to), so that it could be further filtered down. If I called .all() as you suggested, then it appears to resolve the query into an actual list of results.